# laravel route parameters return null on unittest

Tags: laravel, routes, phpunit, route-parameters

I got a problem on phpunit
I'm design route as

```
/v1/outlet/{outlet_id}/test


Route::get('outlets/{outlet_id}/test', ['as' => 'test'], function(){
    return app('request')->route('outlet_id');
});
```

It's working when i call it in postman or brower 
but in phpunit show out as error

```
Call to a member function parameter() on array
```

test code

```
$req = $this->call('GET', '/v1/outlets/1/test');
$this->assertResponseStatus(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `outlets` plural in your test but `outlet` singular in your route definition.

Comment: Do you have example for this ?

Comment: Yes, change your test to be `/v1/outlet/1/test` or change your route to `/v1/outlets/{outlet_id}/test`

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the code `use WithoutMiddleware` from your testing class if it is there and try.